# Antd Month DatePicker view is not rendering correcty

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
const monthFormat = 'YYYY/MM';
<DatePicker defaultValue={moment('2015/01', monthFormat)} format={monthFormat} picker="month" />
```

Is not rendering as per month calendar expectation

Comment: [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also got the issue. As per the Antd documentation I have mention picker type in the component. But it's not working. Then I have tried another way.

Import month picker directly from the antd datepicker.

```
const { RangePicker, MonthPicker } = DatePicker;
```

Then I have used MonthPicker component like as below.

```
<MonthPicker placeholder="Select month" />
```

It's working as per your expectation. Try with this.